# highlighting the selected option of navigation bar where every option takes to new page

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to highlight the clicked option of navigation bar where every option links to new page....

```
 <div class="blue_grad">
                <ul id="nav_bar" class="tabNavigation">          
                    <li><a href="/xyz">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/xdz">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/ycz">E</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/xwz">S</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/xqz">E</a></li>

                </ul>
    </div>
```

I used something like this ... but it didn't work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav_bar li").click(function(){
    $("#nav_bar li").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
 });
});
</script>
```

Any help .....

Comment: seems to work on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uAht2/ ofcourse if you redirect you won't see the effect. therefore i added e.preventDefault();

Comment: Do you want the page to reload and apply the class on the new page?

Comment: when i click on the link its directs me to the new page and i want to see the effect on the new page... hope i am clear

Comment: So if you have static HTML pages (one for each of the nav links) then just put the selected class on the corresponding nav item. If the pages are generated dynamically then use some templating logic to apply the class to the correct item. If you let us know which templating / scripting language you are using we could give you some help with this if needed.

Comment: I am using django framework.... before i had this nav bar on each template but now i moved it to base template to make the code cleaner....

Comment: moving the nav bar into the base template sounds like a good idea, please see the link in my answer below. Good luck with your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick jsfiddle of a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LyjcU/

Comment: Tim's prevent default is much more elegant than return false in my js fiddle.

Comment: OK, so you want the class to be applied on the new page? Then I would not do this using js. What are you using to build your HTML templates? PHP?

Comment: OK, great. There a few answers on here already then which will help you out. Please see this link for some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428599/django-figure-out-which-item-in-a-menu-that-has-been-selected